# Convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a-\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2x}} \,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I am trying to determine the values of $a$ for which the following integral converges:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a-\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2x}} \,dx.$$

My lecturer has stated that this converges for $a<\frac{1}{2}$ but I want to understand why. I did not get anywhere by substituting this value of $a$ into the integral.

Comment: Put $y=\frac 1 {2x}$. $\int_0^{\infty} y^{b}e^{-y}dy$ converges if and only if $b +1 >0$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.
Please [don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189). It looks bad and confusing, and it rarely appears in professional mathematics typesetting.  You know the $p$-test for improper integrals?

Answer (score 0):

Use $$\int_{0}^{\infty}z^c e^{-bz} dz=\frac{\Gamma(c+1)}{b^{c+1}}$$
Let $x=1/z \implies dx=-dz/z^2,$ then the given integral is
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a-1/2} e^{-1/(2x)}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} z^{-a-3/2} e^{-z/2} dz= 2^{-a-1/2} \Gamma(-a-1/2).$$
As $\Gamma(s)$ is finite if $s \ne 0,-1,-2,-3,...$. So $I$ converges for $a \ne n-1/2$, if $n=1,2,3,...$

Comment: What is $s\in I^- +\{0\}$ supposed to mean?

Comment: This means $s$ is not a negative integer or zero.

Comment: The repeated use of $I$ makes it rather confusing. Better would be $s\notin \{\mathbb{Z}\backslash \mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: Oh! yes your are right, I have changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the integral is improper for $x\to 0$ and $x\to \infty$ you may first split it into two parts:

$x\geq 1$:

Here you can estimate $1 \leq e^{\frac 1{2x}}\leq e$ and it follows

$$\int_1^{\infty}x^{a-\frac{3}{2}} \,dx \leq \int_1^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-\frac{3}{2}}}{e^{\frac{1}{2x}}} \,dx \leq \frac 1e\int_1^{\infty}x^{a-\frac{3}{2}} \,dx$$
But $\int_1^{\infty}x^{a-\frac{3}{2}} \,dx$ converges if and only if $a-\frac 32 < -1 \Leftrightarrow \boxed{a<\frac 12}$.

$0<x\leq 1$:

Note that using the series expansion of the exponential function you have $e^{\frac 1{2x}} \geq \frac{\left(\frac 1{2x}\right)^n}{n!} = \frac 1{2^nn!x^n}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, choosing $n$ large enough, you have

$$0\leq \int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{x^{a-\frac{3}{2}}}{e^{\frac{1}{2x}}}  \,dx \leq 2^nn!\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-\frac{3}{2}+n}  \,dx <\infty$$